# Div doesn't fade out after completion in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

#cal div doesn't fade out after completion in jQuery.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="price"></div>
    <div id="cal">Calculating...</div>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript/jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cal').hide();
    $('#price_submit').click(function() {
        var my_data = {
            //successfully sends data
        };

        $('#price').fadeOut('fast', function(){
          $('#cal').fadeIn(); 
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "proccess.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: my_data,
            success: function(msg){
              $('#cal').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                  $('#price').fadeIn().html(msg);
              });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

at last it will successfully retrieve data and shows it but it still shows the #cal div bellow price. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Could it be because your fadeIn() hasn't finished by the time your Ajax call has finished? So the call to fadeOut() notices a fade already in progress, and is ignored?

Comment: are you sure the ajax call was successful

Comment: check if your ajax is responding

Comment: Are you sure your success function is getting called?
I also prefer the shorthand notation for standard post calls:
$.post("process.php", my_data, function(msg) { $('#cal').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                  $('#price').fadeIn().html(msg);
              });

Comment: Thank you, ajax respond is OK because I'm seeing the result. I still can't find the catch.

Answer (score 6):

I'll suggest you to stop previous animations and see:

```
$('#cal').stop().fadeOut('fast', function () {
    $('#price').stop().fadeIn().html(msg);
});
```

Comment: Thank you but is this way nothing happens and it doesn't show the loader but I seems to stop in middle of fading.

Comment: what about .stop(false,true); ?

Answer (score 2):

I have just put your code

```
$('#cal').hide();

$('#price_submit').click(function() {
  var my_data = {
    //successfully sends data
  };

  $('#price').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#cal').fadeIn(); 
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: "/echo/json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: my_data,
    success: function(msg){
        msg = '1134141234';
        $('#cal').fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $('#price').fadeIn().html(msg);
        });
      }
    }
  );
  return false;
});
```

on

http://jsfiddle.net/pfpqv/ and it works just fine.

Can you give some more info to proper reproduce this your problem?